# JQUERY- show div on li click else hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found the fiddle below and what I am trying to do is to make '#overlay' div to hide when I click somewhere else than on '.album' li.  Li '.album' should show '#overlay' div when clicked but when I click on '.album2' it should dissapear.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cgZCc/273/)

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".album").click(function() {
$("#overlay").css("visibility", "visible");
```

CSS

```
#overlay { visibility: hidden; }
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="album" id="nirvana-nevermind">
    hello
     <div id="overlay">
          <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind
     </div>
</li>

   <li class="album2" id="eminem">
    hello

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this:

```
    $('#eminem').click(function(){
    $("#nirvana-nevermind").css("display","none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide `#overlay` when `.album2` is clicked, use

```
$(".album2").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Check the [Updated Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cgZCc/275/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display` `none` instead of `visibility` `hidden`. Although which method you are using will work definitely, but just will make the div invisible and it will keep occupying it's space.

```js
$(".album").click(function() {
  $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
  //or you can use hide() method like below:
  //$("#overlay").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="album" id="nirvana-nevermind">
    hello
     <div id="overlay">
          <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind
     </div>
</li>

   <li class="album2" id="eminem">
    hello

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you this method:

```
$('ul>li').on('click', function(){
  $('ul>li').not(this).find('#overlay').css('visibility','hidden');
  if ($(this).find('#overlay').length) {
     $(this).find('#overlay').css('visibility','visible');
     }
});
```

It waits to click on `li` element then `hidding` all `#overlay` (not clicked one) and checks if `this li` contains overlay inside of it, then set `visibility` to `visible` (nothing changes if already visible), this will work with more `li` elements and more overlays within them.

```js
$('ul>li').on('click', function(){
  $('ul>li').not(this).find('#overlay').css('visibility','hidden');
  if ($(this).find('#overlay').length) {
     $(this).find('#overlay').css('visibility','visible');
     }
});
```

```css
#overlay { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="album" id="nirvana-nevermind">
      hello
      <div id="overlay">
           <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="album2" id="eminem">hello</li>
   <li class="album2" id="">hello2</li>
   <li class="album2" id="">hello3</li>
   <li class="album2" id="">
      hello with overlay
      <div id="overlay">
           New overlay here
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And also, you should know that `visibility` will always be there, even if its setted to `hidden`.. The alternative is to use `display` `none|block` and it will not expand the content if it's hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much! your solution seems to be the closest but using it  overlay has to be placed within li brackets which I dont want. I want to display it outside li brakets so I could style it. Any further help?

Comment: There is a too much ways that can fit what you were asking, but first you have to know, you can style #overlay even inside of li elements also? Or you are planing something else, if you do, There's a way to make a connection at some way so you can recognize that the overlay is fitting to that `li element`.. Update your answer with the plan how do you wish to order them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".album").click(function() {
    if($("#overlay").hasClass("hiden"))
    $("#overlay").removeClass("hiden").addClass("show");
});
$(".album2").click(function() {
    if($("#overlay").hasClass("show"))
     $("#overlay").removeClass("show").addClass("hiden");
});

});
```

```css
.show { visibility: visible; }
.hiden { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="album" id="nirvana-nevermind">
        hello
         <div id="overlay" class="hiden">
              <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind
         </div>
    </li>
    
       <li class="album2" id="eminem">
        hello
        
    </li>
      
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :not selector for adding exceptions in the clicking elements you can find more on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp)